# Stop KeyboardInterrupt reaching batch file processor

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, windows-console

I'm writing some code in Python 3 on Windows that looks like this:

```
try:
    do something that takes a long time
    (training a neural network in TensorFlow, as it happens)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('^C')
print a summary of results
still useful even if the training was cut short early
```

This works perfectly if run directly from the console with `python foo.py`.

However, if the call to Python was within a batch file, it ends up doing all the above but then still spamming the console with the 'terminate batch job' prompt.

Is there a way to stop that happening? By fully eating the ^C within Python, jumping all the way out of the batch file or otherwise?

Comment: You can't control that from Python. Every process that's attached to a console host (conhost.exe) receives console control events on a new thread that gets created by the session server (csrss.exe). CMD's handler sets a flag. When it resumes its dispatch loop after Python exits, it sees the Ctrl+C flag is set and prints the "terminate batch job" message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `break` ([More info here](https://www.computerhope.com/breakhlp.htm)) command in the batch file, which will disable CTRL+C halting the file

**EDIT:** According to [this site](https://www.computerhope.com/breakhlp.htm) of the break command

> Newer versions of Windows (Windows ME, Windows 2000, Windows XP, and higher) only include this command for backward compatibility and turning the break off has no effect.

I personally tested this, and can confirm, I will edit when I find a workaround

**EDIT #2:** If you could have a second batch script that runs `start "" /b /wait cmd /c "yourfile.bat"` although, this is known to cause glitches with other nested batch files

The flag to disable Ctrl+C is inherited by child processes, so Python will no longer raise a KeyboardInterrupt. Plus we still have bugs here in Python if reading from the console gets interrupted by Ctrl+C without getting a SIGINT from the CRT. The Python script should manually enable Ctrl+C via ctypes. Use import ctypes; kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True); success = kernel32.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(None, False)

**EDIT #3** As pointed by Eryksyn (in the comments), you can use [cytpes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) to *ENABLE* it;

```
import ctypes; 
kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True); success = kernel32.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(None, False)
```

**EDIT #4:** I think I found it, try this (Although it may not work) Can you use the [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) import?

```
import time
from threading import Thread

def noInterrupt():
    for i in xrange(4):
        print i
        time.sleep(1)

a = Thread(target=noInterrupt)
a.start()
a.join()
print "done"
```

Comment: CMD's `start` command uses the `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` process creation flag, which causes `CTRL_C_EVENT` to be ignored by default, but you'll still see the terminate request for  `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT`.

Comment: The flag to disable Ctrl+C is inherited by child processes, so Python will no longer raise a `KeyboardInterrupt`. Plus we still have bugs here in Python if reading from the console gets interrupted by Ctrl+C *without* getting a `SIGINT` from the CRT. The Python script should manually enable Ctrl+C via ctypes. Use `import ctypes;` `kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True);` `success = kernel32.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(None, False)`.

Comment: ctypes is being used to *enable* Ctrl+C in Python, not *disable* it. This has no effect on any other existing process that's attached to the console. Ctrl+C will still be disabled in the parent CMD shell that executes the batch script. Processes spawned by Python, however, will inherit Ctrl+C in an enabled state.

Comment: Oh! My bad! I'll fix that! Really sorry

Comment: I don't see the relevance of the threading suggestion. Only the main thread gets a `KeyboardInterrupt` for a C runtime `SIGINT` signal, which is in turn for the console's `CTRL_C_EVENT`. We're going out of our way to enable this console control event in Python, so the OP can actually get and handle a `KeyboardInterrupt`, while having it remain disabled for the batch script. This convoluted setup is an alternative to running the Python script in its own console via `start`. The latter has the advantage of being self-contained within the batch script, but at the cost of using another console.